# Data processing - random projection and subsampling .. what is the right order to do all of them?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a text binary classification task for negative and positive samples, I want to include all of the following:

- Processing the data .. (such as tokenizing)
- Feature selection such as Chi2
- Applying random projection as I have a large sparse matrix (n_samples: 974, n_features: 19329)
- Applying downsampling technique

Then classifying the data

My question is what is the right order to do all these ?
right now I am doing the downsampling first then for each subsample I feed the data to the following:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
('vectorizer',  CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokens)),
('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
('classifier',SVC()) ])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

and after predicting, I repeat the process for the next subsample

I just want to ask is doing it in a different order will yield to a different results or it will give the same thing? e.g. applying the feature extraction and selection on the whole training data then perform the subsampling vs doing the subsampling first ?

Comment: My advice to you is to use SGDClassifier with class_weight ='balanced' instead and avoid reducing the information in your dataset by downsampling or projection. Also try binary=True for CountVectorizer or even use HashingVectorizer altogether. They are very fast and there will be no need to reduce your dataset http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical ordering would be:

1. Processing the data .. (such as tokenizing) - this is always a first step as all following techniques require data to be in vectorized format
2. Feature selection such as Chi2 and Applying random projection as I have a large sparse matrix (n_samples: 974, n_features: 19329) - these two techniques are both part of general dimensionality reduction process, thus they are actually part of the same step and there is no typical ordering (I would actually suggest not to use features selection at all, as this technique removes information from your data, which is rarely a good idea. It is better to leave all the information in and built a stronger classifier on top rather then strenghten the weak one through heuristic removal of features).
3. Applying downsampling technique - this step reduces amount of information thus if it is applied (and it is raraly a good idea - there are plenty of techniques to deal with imbalance which do not reduce amount of information) it should bt in the last possible moment